# How do I write a regex for the following?

Tags: java

I want to write a regular expression so that I can find all groups of words like below:
`"{the cat}"` so the regex should match the string `"{the cat}"` or any alpha-numeric characters including ":"?

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you expecting us to do everything? :|

Comment: This is what I understand from your question. Your regex `String` would be `"(\\Q{the cat}\\E)"`

Answer (score 1):

The following matches all `keys` in `sentence`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "There is the cat";
    String[] keys = {"the", "cat"};        

    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder("");
    for(String key: keys)
        pattern.append("\\b"+key+"\\b|");

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern.substring(0, pattern.length()-1));
    Matcher m = r.matcher(sentence);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println("("+m.group()+", start:"+m.start()+", end:"+m.end()+")");
}
```

And the output:

```
(the, start:9, end:12)
(cat, start:13, end:16)
```

Comment: Since @Phoenix is programming in Java, you can probably omit the Python-specific parts...